Is there an naoqi SDK for Python 3?
I can't seem to find a Python NaoQi SDK for Python 3? All I find is for Python 2.7 from the reference installation page: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/python/install_guide.html
The latest version of the SDK (2.8) requires Python 2.7 and when I use it with Python 3.7 erros occur and the program couldn't be executed correctly.
Any clues if such SDK is available ?

This confused me for a while, too. The answer is that the python 3 version isn't named naoqi , it is called the qi framework now and it is not available for download at Aldebaran, Softbank or United Robotics. You can just install it by calling
pip install qi
Softbank's/Aldebaran's Documentation Page is kind of wibbly wobbly, timey wimey, with many old naoqi examples in it, but good starting points for using the qi framework with python 3 are

application example for handling touch events,
locomotion control tutorial / session example,
Python qi API reference.


NAOqi 2.8 works with python 3?

NAOqi as the robot's operating system has its APIs and you can use multiple SDKs to implement your projects. There are SDKs for C++, Python, JavaScript and there has been a Java SDK for NAOqi 2.4.

The Python SDK has two different flavors: There is a Python 2 SDK named the "NAOqi framework" and a Python 3 SDK named the "qi framework".
The Python 3 qi framework was introduced with NAOqi (OS) 2.4 . NAOqi 2.8 supports this qi framework as it does the NAOqi framework (SDK).
If you want to write an application in python 3 you have to use the qi framework and not the NAOqi framework, which only supports python 2. The OS will be NAOqi in every case.

there are two Python libraries for controlling NAO:

naoqi
qi (also called libqi)

naoqi is older and deprecated; and only qi has been ported to Python 3. You can either install it with pip (pip install qi), or rebuild libqi-python from source.
HOWEVER, this is only for usinq qi on your own computer (and connect to NAO from there). If you want to install things on NAO, see the more complete guide here.
